# Trouble uploading a file using php (using a Linode server)

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image though my php script (around 89kb in size). The code for my index.php is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="file_uploader.php" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="100" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is placed in the same directory as file_uploader.php

and then the code for file_uploader.php is:

```
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{
   copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "" ) or 
           //Exit and show the error message, die does this
           die( "Could not copy file!");
}
else
{
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>
<li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];  ?> bytes
<li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];  ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The permissions of the directory index and file_uploader are in are : 755.

The script seems to load but I get the error "Could not copy file", not sure what is going on here. Could someone give me some pointers please? Thanks!!

Comment: Could you post the entire original error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/copy) and then please explain what `copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "" )` is supposed to do? If I were you I would fix that statement as well as replace it with a more secure variant that was created specifically for this: [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file).

Additionally, read through [this section in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and you might find another bug in your code; if you'd use `$_FILES[0]['tmp_name']` might make it work even better.

Putting all this together; I'd use:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[0]['tmp_name'], __DIR__ .'/'. $_FILES[0]['name']);
```

Comment: copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "" ) is supposed to take the file submitted via post and save it to the server (in the same location as index.php).

Comment: Well, it doesn't do that, right? I'll add copy/pasteble code for you

Comment: @KexAri does my suggestion work for you? Please reply or mark properly

Comment: hey, sorry! Yeah I managed to get it working using a variant of this. Seems like the key was that I wasn't using move_uploaded_file. Been following what it seems an out of date tutorial. Thanks for ur answer